# Cant use loadHTMLfile or file_get_contents for external URL

Tags: php, dom, xpath, file-get-contents

I want to know Groupon active deals so I write a scraper like:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.groupon.com/browse/new-york?category=food-and-drink&minPrice=1&maxPrice=999');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query("//li[@class='slot']//a/@href");
foreach($entries as $e) {
  echo $e->textContent . '<br />';
}
```

but when I run this function browser loading all time, just loading something but don't show any error.

How can I fix it? Not just case with Groupon - I also try other websites but also don't work. WHy?

Comment: Using `@` in `@$dom` will suppress any errors in loading the URL, remove it and you may see what is happening.

Comment: I remove it but browser again loading and dont stop

Comment: maybe they have an api that  you can use instead, probably because they don't want you scraping their pages, probably you could spoof the browser agent or cookie or something, but i'd suggest use an api instead

Answer (score 1):

What about using CURL to loading page data.

`Not just case with Groupon - I also try other websites but also don't work`

I think this code will help you but you should expect unexpected situations for each website which you want to scrap.

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$data = get_url_content('https://www.groupon.com', true);
@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query("//label");

foreach($entries as $e) {
    echo $e->textContent . '<br />';
}


function get_url_content($url = null, $justBody = true)
{

    /* Init CURL */
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, []);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($justBody)
        $data = @(explode("\r\n\r\n", $data, 2))[1];

    var_dump($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I cant load any website, thats very strange

Comment: I guess it is because of Apache misconfiguration. Maybe reinstalling Apache [or other http server] could solve your problem, or test it on another machine

Comment: hm, no I got this message after may attempts: file_get_contents(https://www.groupon.com/browse/new-york?category=food-and-drink&amp;minPrice=30&amp;maxPrice=999): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Comment: code works perfect!